# How to browse parameters of a class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I've created this function to get an object Etape by its type

```
getEtapeByType(typeEtape:TypesEtapesEnum):Etape {
        for (var i in this) {
            if (this[i] instanceof Etape) {
                if (this[i].typeEtape == TypesEtapesEnum.typeEtape) {
                    return this[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My objects Etape are created in the constructor of this class. I don't have any error. But my function returns the same etape, for differents typeEtape. The  etape returned is the first element in my class. It seem that my loop for don't work correctly. Should I use other instruction instead of for...in?

Comment: try `===` instead of `==`, and you don't seem to be using the `typeEtape` from the function call

Comment: I've tried === instead of ==, but I still have the same problem

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've changed my function using correctly typeEtape, and this time my function returns null !

Comment: getEtapeByType(typeEtape:TypesEtapesEnum):Etape {
        for (var i in this) {
            if (this[i] instanceof Etape) {
                if (this[i].typeEtape == typeEtape) {
                    return this[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

Comment: you can try and write out this[i] with console.log("etape at ", i, " is ", this[i]) so you can check for yourself in every step of the for loop

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've checked with console.log('etape at', i,'is',this[i]); that my loop work correctly

Comment: I solved the problem by changing `if (this[i].typeEtape == TypesEtapesEnum.typeEtape)`  to  `if (this[i].typeEtape == typeEtape)`, and modifying the creation of my Etapes. So my loop for worked correctly et that is the correct way to browse parameters of a class.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by changing

```
if (this[i].typeEtape == TypesEtapesEnum.typeEtape)
```

to

```js
if (this[i].typeEtape == typeEtape)
```

and modifying the creation of my Etapes. So my loop for worked correctly and that is the correct way to browse parameters of a class ;)